# Publishing a ASP.NET Core 2.1 production web site for the first time

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

On my old asp.net web forms site I simply ftp'd all the files and folder to the commercial hosting site using a ftp client, changed the web.config to point to the live SQL Server and the debug settings etc and it worked. I created it in Visual Studio 2015 and didn't do any 'publishing' in VS.

Fast forward a few years and I have re-developed the site using ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1 and am ready to launch it live for the first time.

Do I simply ftp all the folders files like before or do I need to go through the 'publish routine' in Visual Studio (2017)? Which I'm not sure how to go about and if I need to change any of my setting files (other than the db connection string) from my dev environment to production?

Note, it's a commercial hosting site and I have no access to IIS settings etc.

Comment: Try to use VS's publish tool (right click on the project and select "publish") first but this will depend on your host so you may end up having to contact them.

Comment: First ensure that your hosting provider provide .NET Core hosting because for hosing ASP.NET Core apps the .NET CLR version of Application Pool needs to be set to `No Managed Code`. Then you will need to publish the ASP.NET Core application and ftp the published files on host server.

Comment: I have found out the hosting site only supports Core 2.0.5 so firstly I have to down covert my web site to 2.0 which shouldn't be an problem as that it what I mainly developed it on.

Comment: Please refer to http://dotnet4hosting.asphostportal.com/post/How-to-Publish-ASPNET-Core-2.aspx. You can always ask your hosting provider to install the latest version for you.

Answer (score 0):

The publish dialog from inside Visual Studio works 100% perfectly as long as you have the correct settings and your hosting allows for A) Windows hosting and B) .NET Core 2.1

I would suggest looking at the details for your hosting (i.e. make sure that it is Windows hosting with .NET Core 2.1 support). Some hosting providers may not have updated to the latest version, but creating a support ticket and asking them to install it on their server usually isn't a big issue.

You can then create a Publish profile with the information from your host and do a one click publish directly to your site or via FTP.

Please see here: [Link to Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Comment: OK, i've changed my web app to net core 2.0.
Published to folder from VS  and then ftp to host (i'll take your advice and ftp directly for future publishes).
Seems ok apart from missing site.css

A couple of Qs...
I've since had to make some minor changes to my _Layout.cshtml so do I have to publish the whole site again?  Can I just publish the changed files (which ever they are?)
Is there a way of making my json db connection string dynamic so I dont have to keep manually change it?

Comment: Publish the whole site again but the VS managed to only make a new publish for the files that have changed, so subsequent publishes should be faster. When are you manually changing the connection string?

Comment: I'm manually changing it in VS before i publish, but now that it's published i shouldnt need to publish it again so i've changed my local version back to the local settings.  I just have to be mindful and not re-publish it.  Im sure there ust be a better, dynamic method?